# Apache logs just "plesklog"

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, log-files

I just discovered that my Apache 2.2.8  just logs in his access_log the string `plesklog` since a few weeks. Normally it looks like that

`www.xxx.yyy.zzz - - [19/Jul/2013:04:37:32 +0600] "GET /infos.html HTTP/1.1" 200 12371 "http://www.yahoo.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"`

Currently it looks like that:

```
plesklog
plesklog
plesklog
plesklog
plesklog
[...]
```

My apache2.conf looks like that:

```
[...]
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %T %{mod_php_memory_usage}n" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %T %{mod_php_memory_usage}n" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
[...]
```

Comment: You need to look at the CustomLog directive.  I suspect there is a faulty format given there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the comment of [kekkis](https://serverfault.com/users/136049/kekkis) I discovered that all my `CustomLog [path]`'s of my VirtualHosts had specified a LogFormat name `plesklog` so I added in my main apache configuration file the line:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %T %{mod_php_memory_usage}n" plesklog
```

And now everything gets logged as it should.